# Why does my Windows 7 box sometimes go into "lock screen" mode when NOT idle?

Tags: windows-7

My computer is configured to go into "lock screen" mode after it has sat idle for a few minutes for security purposes.  This usually works fine.

However, starting sometime in the past month or two it will sometimes enter the "lock screen" when I am actively using the computer.  It just happened just now while I was typing some code into Visual Studio.

This happens a few times a day.  I guess it's relatively harmless as I can just enter my password and continue, but it is still extremely annoying.

I need to pay more attention to the timing to know for sure, but it ***might*** be happening at similar times everyday.

Anyone have any ideas about why this might be happening?

Answers to commentators:

- I am definitely not hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> myself. That how I manually lock system when I know I'm going to be away for a while.  I'd know it if I typed it. Unknown if something else is doing it.
- Only scheduled tasks (that are visible to my user) are a updaters for Google Chrome and GoToMeeting
- Computer is at my house, but it is on work's LAN via a VPN tunnel appliance (Aruba), and is a member of work's Active Directory.  There are GPOs in effect, but I don't know what they are.
- Can't disable locking.  It's evidently GPO'd.
- Haven't tried a new keyboard, but I touch type, so I'd notice if it where getting glitchy.
- Don't have any other user credentials to log in with.  It's on work's AD.

Comment: Are you (or something else) unintentionally triggering Win+L? If you suspect it's timed, have you checked for scheduled tasks that may be doing it?  Are you on a LAN?  Are you at work? If you disable the idle-lock, does it still happen at theses unexpected times? Have you tried a new keyboard? Have you tried logged in as another user?

Comment: I think you need to read techie007 comments, answer them all because until then it's going to be really hard to diagnose this as there are just so many possibilities.

Comment: I've been getting this issue for ages, and whenever I google it, I get answers (including many from Microsoft customer support) saying to simply increase the idle lock time, or turn off the lock screen entirely. The first suggestion seems irrelevant, and the second is undesirable. What would cause windows to stop registering input for the purpose of determining that the PC is idle?